# Creating a cron job in SQL server that executes a procedure every day

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on SQL server and  have a procedure that takes data from one table and put into other table. I want to execute  this procedure every midnight. I have searched on this
I didn't find a proper  way to achieve this.

My procedure is "archive_table_sp" I want to run this every day at 12 midnight

Comment: Have you considered EVENT https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html

Comment: Your question is tagged sql-server and MySQL please remove the irrelevant tag.

Comment: Sounds like a job for [SQL Server Agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent). If you're on SQL Server, that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like setting up a SQL Server Agent Job.

You can do something like this, and it is fairly simple. As long as you have full access to the SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), you should be able to set this up.

Below is the command (T-SQL) way of doing it. I would use GUI method as it is probably easier (please see the link down below for detail).

```
USE msdb ;  
GO  
EXEC dbo.sp_add_job  
    @job_name = N'Weekly Sales Data Backup' ;  
GO  
EXEC sp_add_jobstep  
    @job_name = N'Weekly Sales Data Backup',  
    @step_name = N'Set database to read only',  
    @subsystem = N'TSQL',  
    @command = N'ALTER DATABASE SALES SET READ_ONLY',   
    @retry_attempts = 5,  
    @retry_interval = 5 ;  
GO  
EXEC dbo.sp_add_schedule  
    @schedule_name = N'RunOnce',  
    @freq_type = 1,  
    @active_start_time = 233000 ;  
USE msdb ;  
GO  
EXEC sp_attach_schedule  
   @job_name = N'Weekly Sales Data Backup',  
   @schedule_name = N'RunOnce';  
GO  
EXEC dbo.sp_add_jobserver  
    @job_name = N'Weekly Sales Data Backup';  
GO
```

For more information, please go to the following:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-job?view=sql-server-ver15
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/schedule-a-job?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Tip: The code you posted is eerily similar to code on the first page you provided a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-job?view=sql-server-ver15) for. Link-only answers are bad things as links often go stale. Copying the appropriate information from another source _with attribution_ is preferable. [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) explains how it should be done. It is, of course, possible that you carefully crafted similar code to solve a similar problem. That happens all the time.